# How to insert dates dynamically while adding a data into a table?

Tags: sql-server, date, format

I am using the following script to insert data into a table

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].table_1() RETURNS TABLE
RETURN (
  SELECT *
  FROM (VALUES
    (1, 'Your Birthday is in 2018-10-31 11:29:32.4066667'),
    (2, 'Your Friends Birthday is in 2019-01-31 11:29:32.4066667')
  ) AS t(id, message)
)
```

What I want is to add the dates dynamically based on the date the script is run.

I can do that using `DATEADD(DAY, -101, GETDATE())`.

Is there any way I can use the `DATEADD` function in message column in the above script?

Comment: Add *what* dates dynamically? Your `function` has no parameters, and also performs no `INSERT` (not that it could, a `function` cannot perform DML statements).

Comment: I have got another synchronization script that runs the function and inserts data into the respective table.

Comment: Also, who's birthday is exactly at `11:29:32.4066667`? Birthdays are a date, or a specific time and day.

Comment: *"I have got another synchronization script ..."* that doesn't explain anything though.

Comment: @Larnu It is just a format that GETDATE() returns. I will be filtering the data in the front end. So it doesnot matter.

Comment: `  SELECT @sql = CONCAT(@sql, 'MERGE ', @table, ' AS t USING ', @function, ' AS s');` The script inserts data like this. `    EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to [`convert`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) the date back to string:

```
SELECT 'Your Birthday is in ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), DATEADD(DAY, -101, GETDATE()), 103)
```

Comment: I cannot use select statement like that i have to add the data in message column, similar to the format i have used above. Will the  `CONVERT` work there too? I tried using `JSON AUTO` but it did not work.